# Not compile code of angular 5 in prod mode

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular5

I am using this code

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { MainModule } from './main/main.module';
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';
const routes: Routes = [
{path: '', redirectTo: 'auth', pathMatch: 'full'},
{path: 'login' , redirectTo: 'auth' , pathMatch: 'full'},
{path: 'auth', loadChildren: () => AuthModule }
];
@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

It works with ng build but did not work with prod mode  'ng build --prod'

**Error:**

> ERROR in app/app.module.ts(20,5): Error during template compile of
>   'AppModule' Function expressions are not supported in decorators in
>   'AppRoutingModule' 'AppRoutingModule' references 'ɵ0' 'ɵ0' contains
>   the error at app/app-routing.module.ts(9,33) Consider changing the
>   function expression into an exported function.

Comment: can you be precise with the problem? Show some error string or something to get us started...

Comment: ERROR in app/app.module.ts(20,5): Error during template compile of 'AppModule'
  Function expressions are not supported in decorators in 'AppRoutingModule'
    'AppRoutingModule' references 'ɵ0'
      'ɵ0' contains the error at app/app-routing.module.ts(9,33)
        Consider changing the function expression into an exported function.

Comment: remove `exports: [RouterModule],` from @NgModule then give it a try

Comment: still same isuee

Comment: can you share the repo?

Answer (score 3):

```
{path: 'auth', loadChildren: () => AuthModule }
```

This line is your problem. The AoT compilation cannot manage the funciton expression, it needs static references.
Replace with this:

```
{path: 'auth', loadChildren: './auth/auth.module#AuthModule' }
```